# How to get Jupyter working after Python change 32bit -> 64bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I installed 64-bit Python and uninstalled 32-bit Python so that I can use tensorflow. Now when I try to use Jupyter I get:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\jupyter.exe" --runtime-dir': The system cannot find the file specified.

What's the best way to fix this? Do I have to reinstall Jupyter or can I just change the specified executables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You should reinstall Juypter notebook It's best and easy way to fix it.

Comment: How it should be installed? Please, explain about details of installation and why your idea should be worked.

Comment: Go to anaconda website and you can download anaconda setup If anaconda is already installed then Go to anaconda navigoter and from their you can install Juyper notebook. To uninstall Juyper notebook you can use conda uninstall jupyter notebook in Terminal.